# I see my dog run

Tags: word, wordplay

> My dog chooses not to go after the highest bets.

**What is my dog's name?**

*Bonus:* What is my name?

Comment: (+1): A one-line wonder! :P

Comment: I dunno his name, but the dog is smart.

Comment: As far as I can tell your name is PilsNot3... :D

Comment: @PilsNot3 would a _breed_ be an acceptable name answer? Or am I barking up the wrong tree, so to speak?

Comment: If you can explain why your answer might work, then go ahead, but for the record it actually is a name you would give to a pet dog and not necessarily a breed

Comment: Sounds like a dog I knew once. The butcher bet her £20 that she couldn't jump up and get the meat from on top of his counter. She didn't take the bet though - the steaks were too high.

Comment: I see my dog, "Run." [its name]    I see my dog-run. [a location] .  Punctuation is wonderful.  Yeah I know this is OT.  It's Monday.

Comment: Regarding the bonus question, does your name have anything to do with bcgbzrgel? For example, lbh "frr" lbhe qbt eha

Comment: @MarkS SteveV’s answer already found the correct answer and explained the reference, but if you think you have an alternate answer that also works, then go ahead! :)

Comment: **Congratulations on recieving** _**50 upvotes**_**!** Well done for that, and the amazing puzzle (not to mention that having less than 50 upvotes most certainly does not undermine the quality of your puzzle)! :D

Comment: Thanks @user477343 for your compliments!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Your dog's name is

> Spot

because

> your dog (*Spot*)
> chooses (*opts*)
> not to go (*stop*)
> after (*post*)
> the highest (*tops*)
> bets (*pots*),

which are all

> anagrams of *Spot*.

Comment: Nice one, you got them all! Now, I'll go watch some dogs run before I accept this answer

Answer (score 36):

After looking at everyone else's answers, I know my answer is not correct, but I am just putting it here because I think the wordplay I show here was unintentional, making it *very* cool (and funny, in my opinion). A very clever puzzle! :D

Anyway, without further ado, the dog's name might be

> **George**

`My dog chooses not to go after the highest bets.`

> The line is telling us to go after letters, but not in the highest groups (words). So, go for the letters around each space between them.

> M**y d**o**g c**hoose**s n**o**t t**${}$**o go a**fte**r t**h**e h**ighes**t b**ets. 
>  $\Downarrow$ 
>  **ydgcsnttogoartehtb** (note that the first and last letters are **y** and **b**, respectively).

Rearranging the letters, you get

> **Dog's got that bent cry**

So now this points to

> [Barnyard Dawg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzk93LR5SZw). Barnyard $\to$ **B**arn **y**ard, and also, this dog being from the *Looney Tunes* is of course going to make some weird sounds; however, the actual name of this dog is **George**. In the link, you can also see George **running** after the rooster in a YouTube video, that video actually showing the very first appearance of George.

---

**Bonus:**

According to

> [this profile](https://looneytunes.fandom.com/wiki/Barnyard_Dawg) of George, he was cast as the pet of **Porky Pig**.

So that means your name is

> **PORKY PIG**.

Comment: I love this stuff!! Not correct, but super clever.

Comment: @Brandon_J that was quick! I appreciate the upvote :P

Comment: OK, now *this* is what a convincing incorrect answer should sound like :)

Comment: @PilsNot3 ya shoulda seen [my answer to this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/77651/is-there-a-secret-message-in-the-first-decimals-of-pi/77895#77895).

Comment: @Brandon_J I looked at that yesterday via this link, and I must say, I was *flat-out* impressed! ;)

Comment: Ha. Ha. Ha. Thanks, though; I worked hard on that one:)

Comment: @Brandon_J It was a very surprising answer (and yeah, terrible puns are the best, aren't they?)

Comment: ~~ title changed to **I see my dog pun** ~~ Also, I think you mean that the _first and_ last letters are y and b, not just "the last."

Comment: You could also have "dogs that got bent cry".  Try it, it works!

Comment: @FlorianF yeah, true, but I think it's *slightly* less grammatically correct. Overall, it implies the same thing, though :P

Comment: @Brandon_J oh yes, true that! Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: @MrPie what did I say? Edit: Oh, I see it now :)

Answer (score 17):

> Whisper, the last [royal corgi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_corgis)

Because

> The "highest bets" is Queen Elizabeth II (By wordplay, Elizabeth, Elspeth, Betsy, and Bess...), who has chosen to stop breeding corgis so that she leaves no young pups behind when she passes away.  Her last full breed Corgi went *before*, not after, the "highest bets" QEII who is still alive

So you would be

> Queen Elizabeth II

Comment: That’s a pretty good alternate solution! Will upvote in a bit since I reached my daily vote limit

Answer (score 12):

Maybe your dog's name is

> Spot

Because he does

> just a spot of betting, or maybe just spot (cash)a bets.

If so

> based on your title, you could be Dick or Jane (See Spot run.  Run, Spot, Run.

Comment: Also, regarding the bonus, rot13(jub jnf qbvat gur frrvat?)

Answer (score 4):

The dog’s name is

> Stay.

It chooses not to go after the highest bets, it stay, so [I google dog named stay and found out the owner](https://www.dogquotations.com/steven-wright-dog-quotes.html)

The owner of the dog is

> Steven Wright.

Comment: May you please explain how you arrived at your answer? Please look at [*How do I write a good answer?*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [***Help Center***](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) for more information.

Comment: In that case, why not "Fold" ?