# Today's Letter Sequence

Tags: letter-sequence

Can you figure out what the next letter in this sequence is?

> C, N, O, I, Z, E

It's a very simple one and will no doubt be cracked in a few minutes, but I thought it was fitting for today.

Comment: *(Raises hand and waves frenetically)* Teacher, teacher, [I know this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/77673/36023)! :-)

Comment: @Bass, ah yes, C-Noize, the universe's favourite artist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule is:

> Their positions in the alphabet are **3, 14, 15, 9, 26, 5** - it's **Pi**!

The next letter is:

> **C**, the **3**rd letter of the alphabet

The puzzle is called 'Today's Letter Sequence' because

> it was posted on March 14th, [Pi Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_Day).